# NHibernate mapping by code - composite unique index

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, unique-constraint, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

How do I create a composite UNIQUE constaint on 3 properties of a class?
It needs to allow NULL as a legitimate value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be one of the ways to go about it..

```
        mapper.Class<MyClass>(ca =>
            {
                ca.Property(x => x.Property1, map => map.UniqueKey("UQ_ComposedUniqueKey"));
                ca.ManyToOne(x => x.FKField1, map => { map.UniqueKey("UQ_ComposedUniqueKey"); map.NotNullable(false); });
            });
```

You can combine many properties or FKs in a single unique key.